# SQL Trigger for keeping another table up to date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I haven't used triggers before but they seem the way to go for this problem.

I want to have a table that has up to date records from two tables: `Item_Master` and `Dev_Master` -> `Union_Master`

The main thing I am not understanding is the inserted and deleted 'tables'. If I want to update a single row (when a row is updated), how do I access the inserted tables columns?

Here is what I have so far:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DevMasterChangeTrigger]
ON [dbo].[DEV_MASTER]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @UpdateType nvarchar(1)
    DECLARE @UpdatedDT datetime

    SELECT @UpdatedDT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
          SELECT @UpdateType = 'U'    -- Update Trigger
       ELSE
          SELECT @UpdateType = 'I'    -- Insert Trigger
    ELSE
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
          SELECT @UpdateType = 'D'    -- Delete Trigger
       ELSE
          SELECT @UpdateType = NULL;  -- Unknown Operation

    IF @UpdateType = 'I'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Insert'
    END

    IF @UpdateType = 'U'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE dbo.UNION_MASTER 
        SET PRDNO = inserted.PRDNO & 'abc' 
        WHERE dbo.DEV_MASTER.PRDNO = inserted.PRDNO
    END

    IF @UpdateType = 'D'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Delete'
    END
```

Also, any good books on immersing one's self into MS SQL Server?

Edit: ok, for anybody that stumbles on this post, I figured it out. Hopefully, I haven't missed any nuance that causes problems. The delete part is a bit of a puzzle to me...

```
USE [abc]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[DevMasterChangeTrigger]    Script Date: 10/04/15 12:43:43 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DevMasterChangeTrigger]
ON [dbo].[DEV_MASTER]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
DECLARE @UpdateType nvarchar(1)
DECLARE @UpdatedDT datetime

SELECT @UpdatedDT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP



IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
        SELECT @UpdateType = 'U'    -- Update Trigger
    ELSE
        SELECT @UpdateType = 'I'    -- Insert Trigger
ELSE
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
        SELECT @UpdateType = 'D'    -- Delete Trigger
    ELSE
        SELECT @UpdateType = NULL;  -- Unknown Operation

IF @UpdateType = 'I'
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO [UNION_MASTER]
   (PRDID, {Insert various fields here})
   SELECT [inserted].[PRDID],   [inserted].{Insert various fields here}
   FROM inserted 
END

IF @UpdateType = 'U'
BEGIN
    UPDATE [UNION_MASTER] 
    SET 
    [UNION_MASTER].[abcdfield]=[inserted].[abcdfield], {other fields here}
    FROM inserted
    WHERE [UNION_MASTER].[PRDNO]=inserted.prdno     
END

IF @UpdateType = 'D'
BEGIN
    declare @prdno varchar(50)
    SELECT @prdno= PRDNO FROM deleted
    DELETE 
    FROM UNION_MASTER 
    WHERE PRDNO = @prdno
END
```

Comment: for the book: try 'Training Kit (Exam 70-461): Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012'
That covers about everything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, `inserted` and `deleted` tables are special tables which can used in DML triggers. These tables contain the rows based on the DML operation performed which actioned the trigger.

`inserted` table contains the row's data which are either inserted for `insert` statement or the newly modified rows in case of an `update`

deleted table contains rows which are deleted in a `delete` operation or old data which has been modified in case of an `update`

In your trigger, you can try something like this

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DevMasterChangeTrigger]
ON [dbo].[DEV_MASTER]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
    DECLARE @UpdateType nvarchar(1)
    DECLARE @UpdatedDT datetime

    SELECT @UpdatedDT = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted) AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
          SELECT @UpdateType = 'U'    -- Update Trigger
       ELSE IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
          SELECT @UpdateType = 'I'    -- Insert Trigger
       ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
          SELECT @UpdateType = 'D'    -- Delete Trigger
       ELSE
          SELECT @UpdateType = NULL;  -- Unknown Operation

    IF @UpdateType = 'I'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Insert'
        // add appropriate logic here
    END

    IF @UpdateType = 'U'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE U dbo.UNION_MASTER 
        SET PRDNO = inserted.PRDNO & 'abc'
        FROM dbo.UNION_MASTER U
        inner join inserted i -- this table will have the rows affected from update statement for table DEV_MASTER
        on i.<UNION_MASTER_ID> = U.<UNION_MASTER_ID> -- USE appropriate joining condition
    END

    IF @UpdateType = 'D'
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Delete'
        // add appropriate logic here
    END
```

Reference links

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2342/understanding-sql-server-inserted-and-deleted-tables-for-dml-triggers/